# Comparing a function result and subselect in MYSQL where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, mysql-function

I can't figure out why this subselect doesn't return anything.

```
select value from mytable where 
indx = @var
and f() in (select num from nums);
```

when this version does:

```
select value from mytable where 
indx = @var
and f() in (2,5,11);
```

When I create a list identical to the results from the subselect, it works, but when using a subselect doesn't.

Also, this works:

```
select value from mytable where 
indx = @var
and 2 in (select num from nums);
```

Comment: Show what the `nums` table looks like.

Comment: `insert into nums values (2),(5),(11);`    Just a simple table for this example.

Comment: What does "doesn't return anything" mean?  Does it return no rows?  Does it return rows with `NULL`values?  Does it just hang?  Does it return an error?

Comment: The first query returns no rows.  The second and third query return one row.